# How to sort array of words alphabiticaly but considering the case of letters?

Tags: ruby, sorting

capitalized words have to go first
**andrew Net andrey Andrew

Andrew andrew andrey Net**

UPD:

**andrew Net andray Andrew

Andrew andray andrew Net**

Comment: I don't know about ruby, but I'll go with parsing the characters to ASCII or UTF and ordering by that.

Comment: What you mean is only use if a letter is capitalized once the words are the same or what?

Comment: You have a -1 from me. There's just no way that 'androy' comes before 'andrew', so clean up your question and in any case my answer should point you in the right direction.

Comment: You should post the code you are working on so people can help you with it.  This is not the place to get someone to do it for you.

Comment: How is `andray` supposed to be changed into `androy` in your second example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can two successive criteria: first the letters (case insensitive) then the letters (with the case). `Array#sort_by` is perfect for these:

```
%w[andrew Net andrey Andrew].sort_by{|w| [w.downcase, w]}
# => ["Andrew", "andrew", "andrey", "Net"]
```

Comment: **andrew Net androy Andrew > Andrew androy andrew Net** What about this?

Comment: @Tensho `%w[andrew Net androy Andrew].sort_by{|w| [w.downcase, w]}` gets you `["Andrew", "andrew", "androy", "Net"]`, not `Andrew androy andrew Net`.

Answer (score 0):

```
b = a.sort { |x,y| (z = x[0].upcase <=> y[0].upcase) == 0 ? x <=> y : z }
```

Comment: Explanation along with answers is much more helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
%w[andrew Net andrey Andrew].sort_by(&:downcase)
```